# Redirecting subdomain to another subdomain, as variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've read all tutorials about `.htaccess` and still don't know:

- Can I redirect subdomain to another subdomain, as variable?

`.htaccess` looks now in that way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I want to redirect:

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

To:

```
subdomain.anotherdomain.com
```

Not specifying subdomain.

So it should redirect:

```
subdomain1.domain.com
```

To:

```
subdomain1.anotherdomain.com
```

And:

```
subdomain2.domain.com
```

To:

```
subdomain2.anotherdomain.com
```

And:

```
subdomain3.domain.com
```

To:

```
subdomain3.anotherdomain.com
```

And so on...

Is it possible to pass `subdomainx` to `$1` and then redirect to `$1.anotherdomain.com`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.anotherdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: OK its working but why it redirecting me from subdomain1.domain.com to subdomain1.anotherdomain.com//

Comment: But that is what you needed right: `subdomain1.domain.com to subdomain1.anotherdomain.com`

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realize I left it as `/%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`. Thanks @Prix.